# How do I only display results that do not have NULL values from a specified column?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatable, datatables

I am using the [DataTables jQuery plugin](https://datatables.net/) to display results from a mySQL database in a chart format. My server-side configuration for this is below:

```
// DB table to use
$table = 'Estimates';

// Table's primary key
$primaryKey = 'CreatedDate';

// Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables.
// The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database, while the `dt`
// parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. In this case simple
// indexes
$columns = array(
array( 'db' => 'Client', 'dt' => 0 ),
array( 'db' => 'EstimateNumber',  'dt' => 1 ),
array( 'db' => 'Status',   'dt' => 2 ),
array( 'db' => 'CurrentEstimateTotal',     'dt' => 3 ),
array( 'db' => 'CreatedDate',     'dt' => 4 )
);

// SQL server connection information
$sql_details = array(
'user' => 'root',
'pass' => 'root',
'db'   => 'tm-charts',
'host' => 'localhost'
);


/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
* If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP
* server-side, there is no need to edit below this line.
*/

require( 'ssp.class.php' );

echo json_encode(
SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
);
```

This processing is largely using the simple server-side processing template provided by DataTables, [which you can view here.](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html)

My question is: How can I edit this template to only display results that do not have a NULL value in the CreatedDate column?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If we knew what the `ssp` class did, we could tell you to construct a query that excludes null values from the DB ?

Comment: if you have a way to edit the query so that it'll filter the results then find it

Comment: @adeneo The ssp.class.php file can be found on GitHub: https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/blob/master/examples/server_side/scripts/ssp.class.php

Comment: Then look at how to use the `filter ( $request, $columns, &$bindings )` method to say `WHERE column IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working!

Here is the answer:

```
echo json_encode(
SSP::complex( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, null, "CreatedDate IS NOT NULL" )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Liz Banach:
You need to include the WHERE condition, as follows:

```
require( 'ssp.class.php' );
$where = "CreatedDate IS NOT NULL";
echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns,$where )
);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I added in this code, and it seems as if the NULL values are still displayed on the front end. Is there anything else I need to do along with including this code?

Comment: What version of Datatables are you using? CreatedDate contains empty values or NULL values?

Comment: I installed it through Bower so I believe it is the latest. I tried to change the `WHERE` query to `$where = "CreatedDate != ''"` in case the values were empty instead of `NULL`, and still saw the empty values in the table. Did I do that wrong?

Comment: Use the following function, instead of SSP:simple... SSP::complex ( $request, $conn, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, $whereResult=null, $whereAll=null )

Comment: When I did that, I received this error message: DataTables warning: table id=aging_projects - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7. Console says: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: Apache error log says: `PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: request in /Users/splashnw/Sites/tm-charts/inc/aging-projects-server-processing.php on line 56, referer: http://tm-charts.dev/tm-data.php
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: conn in /Users/splashnw/Sites/tm-charts/inc/aging-projects-server-processing.php on line 56, referer: http://tm-charts.dev/tm-data.php
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /Users/splashnw/Sites/tm-charts/inc/ssp.class.php on line 359, referer: http://tm-charts.dev/tm-data.php`

Comment: Liz, why are you using CreatedDate as your primary key? Use the id of the table, and try again with the "simple" function"...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120556/discussion-between-liz-banach-and-joel-hernandez).